# How do I convert a string into a number interpreted in certain base in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, arithmetic

I'm simply trying to convert a string `$RECORD_HDR` to a number `$RECORD_SIZE`, where

`echo $RECORD_HDR` gives 003D
and
`echo $RECORD_SIZE` should give 61

Comment: What do `$RECORD_HDR` and `$RECORD_SIZE` actually contain?

Answer (score 4):

From `bash` manual:

> Constants with a leading 0 are interpreted as octal numbers.  A 
>   leading  0x  or  0X denotes  hexadecimal.

Thus:

```
$ RECORD_HDR="003D"
$ RECORD_SIZE=$((0x$RECORD_HDR))
$ echo "$RECORD_SIZE"
61
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This is so much better than what my searches turned up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of ways:

Using the `bc` calculator and explicitly setting the input base (quite portable):

```
RECORD_SIZE=`echo "ibase=16;$RECORD_HDR" | bc`
```

Using arithmetic evaluation with an explicit base (ksh and bash, at least - not sure how portable this construct is):

```
RECORD_SIZE=$((16#$RECORD_HDR))
```

Comment: `$((16#...))` is `ksh`/`zsh`/`bash` only. `$((0x...))` is POSIX. The greatest supported number varies from shell to shell but could be as low as `7FFFFFFF` while for `bc`, there's no limit. With `bc` you need **upper-case** hex digits.

Comment: `pdksh`/`mksh`/`zsh` support bases 2 to 36, `bash`/`ksh93` from 2 to 64 and `bc` from 2 to 16.

Comment: My views on portability are admittedly skewed - I spend too much time on old Solaris systems with non-Posix /bin/sh's...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the awk [Velour library](//github.com/svnpenn/velour):

```
$ velour -n 'print mt_basecon("3D", 16, 10)'
61
```

Or:

```
$ velour -n 'print mt_basecon(ARGV[1], 16, 10)' 3D
61
```